# Инструмент для проверки тестового задания

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Есть 2 сайта.
Первый сайт – оригинал. Это готовый сайт, по примеру которого говорят сделать один из его элементов (допустим, хедер).
Второй сайт – выполненное тестовое задание. Тестовое – повторить хедер. Выполненное задание может лежать по ссылке в сети, или же локально.

Нужно проверять оригинал и тестовое задание на соответствие, сравнивая их. В том числе, на разных разрешениях экрана.
Нужно сделать сайт-инструмент для проверки тестового задания. Страница, на которой в верхней половине экрана будет открываться оригинал, а в нижней – тестовое. Чтобы менялся размер браузерного окна, и при этом одновременно менялась ширина для двух открытых внутри сайтов.
Как это реализовать? Через два тега iframe? Или может есть уже готовое нормально решения для такой задачи? В любом случае, пожалуйста, киньте инфу как хотя бы приблизительно можно такое реализовать. С какой стороны зайти.

[image: Иллюстрация тестового задания]

Comment: Слишком глобальный вопрос

Comment: И как мне его уточнить, чтобы было понятнее?

Comment: Написать, в чем **конкретно** проблема. Например, ошибка в коде, или помощь с откладкой. Импорт сайта, или смена размеров "внутренних сайтов" и тд и тп. Ваш вопрос слишком обобщенный, подойдет под биржу фриланса, но никак не под stackoverfow.

Comment: Два тега iframe в принципе подойдут.

Comment: Сделал через 2 iframe. Получилось но не совсем. Ориг сайт, на который я ссылался - microsoft.
И его iframe не работает. Он мне не дает его подтянуть. "Сайт microsoft.com не позволяет установить соединение." Есть какой-то способ это обойти?

Comment: @Voprositel, нормальный вопрос вроде.

Comment: @Qwertiy, возможно я поторопился с выводами, но все же вопрос слишком обобщённый.

Answer (score 0):

Есть автоматические утилиты для сравнения скриншотов сайтов, например, [BackstopJS](https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS) и [jemini](https://yandex.ru/dev/gemini/). Первый точно умеет сравнивать прям два сайта. Если сравнивать со скриншотами, то они должны быть сделаны (иначе могут быть расхождения из-за способов отрисовки) на том же компьютере, что и скриншоты проверяемого сайта.

Но вряд ли это можно реализовать в рамках сайта, поскольку для выполнения тестов используется управление браузером. Предлагаю вместо этого делать доступным сам отчёт с результатами проверки - его вполне можно хостить как статику.